# Python generate data based on archives

Tags: python, random

I'm working on a operations research project.

I created a heuristic method and I need to test my method intensively to assess its performance.

I have the past data, in form of 3 fields;

**Date, Amount, Type**

What I want is to generate new data, similar to the the existing data. I'm currently doing this with "+/- random".

I there a method or lib to generate original data, similar to the existing data by analysing statistics and trends of the old data.

Comment: I would look into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).  It a data analysis library which allows for this type of functionality.  You may want to research the  `apply` function.

Comment: What's the probability distribution (PD) of your data? Do you want to simulate you data with same overall PD or just randomize (based on normal distribution) each entry? Is 'type' a random variable or you intend to do categorical statistics?

Comment: @SYK , I hoped for a lib that could figure out the PD and generate new data accordingly. I didn't have any done on the PD of my data.

Comment: Then you would need a hypothesis for proper [statistical hypothesis testing] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, you can use pandas.  For example, first generate some dummy data:

```
data = [{'date': 'dummy', 'amount':1, 'type': 'a'},
        {'date': 'dummy' , 'amount':2, 'type': 'a'},
        {'date': 'dummy', 'amount':1, 'type': 'b'},
        {'date': 'dummy', 'amount':1, 'type': 'b'},
        {'date': 'dummy', 'amount':2, 'type': 'c'}]
```

Import the appropriate libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

Import the data into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'amount', 'type'])
```

Output:

```
    date  amount type
0  dummy       1    a
1  dummy       2    a
2  dummy       1    b
3  dummy       1    b
4  dummy       2    c
```

Then apply your random "+/-" data method:

```
df['new  amount'] = df['amount'].apply(lambda amount: amount + (-random.random())**random.randint(1, 2))
```

Results:

```
    date  amount type  new  amount
0  dummy       1    a     1.021583
1  dummy       2    a     1.496697
2  dummy       1    b     0.685394
3  dummy       1    b     1.764432
4  dummy       2    c     2.219713
```

Of course this process will have to be changed based on your exact needs. You can also used pandas for your statistical analysis to come up with other methods to transform your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yet my goals is to write this without a random(). I want a lib that can generate new data based on the statistics of the old data

Comment: @Halox what do you mean by statistics of the old data?

Comment: I means trends, std dev, mean and so on. I want my new data to be more similar to the old data, more than "+/- random" can provide.

Comment: are you just looking for random data drawn from a normal distribution with mean and standard deviation the same?

Comment: for example http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html